# Do I put a comma after this phrase?

Tags: phrases, commas

The context:

> Spearheaded by female reformers Susan B. Anthony, Elizabeth Cady Stanton, and Lucy Stone, a national organization for a newly coined term “Women’s Suffrage” started to emerge, dubbed the NAWSA, standing for the National American Woman Suffrage Association.

*Spearheaded by female reformers Susan B. Anthony,*

Is there supposed to be a comma after *reformers*? I don't think so, but I am not sure.

Comment: [Proofreading alert] You've got a lot of commas already; I'd split it. End a sentence after *emerge*, and rewrite the rest - "It was dubbed... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is a bit confusing. Adding a comma after *reformers* won’t really help, as it could sound like Susan B Anthony et al. were spearheaded by female reformers, rather than being the ones doing the spearheading.

Also, the phrase “a national organization for a newly coined term…” needs a verb – perhaps *named*?

A clearer writing of the sentence might be:

> Spearheaded by the female refromers Susan B. Anthony, Elizabeth Cady
>   Stanton and Lucy Stone – and named for the newly coined term “women’s
>   suffrage” – the National American Woman Suffrage Association (NAWSA)
>   began to emerge.

Breaking it up into two sentences might work as well:

> The National American Woman Suffrage Association (NAWSA) began to
>   emerge. The organisation was named for the newly coined term “women’s suffrage” and was
>   spearheaded by the female refromers Susan B. Anthony, Elizabeth Cady
>   Stanton and Lucy Stone

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble following your answer.  "A national organization of a newly coined term" does have a verb -- "started."  It certainly doesn't need *named* because it already has *dubbed*.   And I think your rewrite changes the sense subtly.  The passage doesn't mean that the NAWSA was named for the term "women's suffrage" in the sense of named after but was established for the term in the sense of to promote it.

Comment: "a national organisation for a newly coined term" doesn't make sense, unless there is a national organisation the purpose of which is a newly coined term.

Comment: "established for the term in the sense of to promote it". If that's the case then is should say "a national organisation started to emerge to promote the newly coined term 'women's suffrage'".

Comment: I don't mean to defend the language as particularly graceful, but I think I can tease out the meaning.  The newly coined term is "women's suffrage", and that thing (women's voting rights) is what the organization was intended to promote, not the term itself.  In other words "a national organization for 'Women’s Suffrage',  that last a newly coined term."  "Newly coined term" serves as modifier of "Women's Suffrage", not as a noun in its own right.

Comment: I think "the newly named *concept* 'women's suffrage'" would be better here.

Comment: The phrase is at best ambiguous. If the author wishes to explicitly state what they meant to say then I'll be happy to amend the suggested wording in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such, you should consult your style manual.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends a comma after an appositive (i.e., a noun or noun phrase that renames something) except if the appositive is restrictive, i.e., unless it defines what it renames. SBA, ECS, and LS form a compound appositive that renames "reformers," but it's restrictive because it defines just those reformers who did the spearheading.  So no comma between "reformers" and its appositive.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is confusing, I don't think a comma is necessary in your sentence. A more simplified version of your comprehension below.

> A national organization for a newly coined term “Women’s Suffrage” has started to emerge.  NAWSA or National American Woman Suffrage Association is spearheaded by female reformers Susan B. Anthony, Elizabeth Cady Stanton, and Lucy Stone.

Comment: You've changed the tense. Where did you get *"recent"* from? Do you think *"emerged a lot"* is a commonly used phrase? And things don't get *"dubbed as"*.

Comment: @JHCL "Emerged a lot" is certainly a bad choice, since the term "Women's Suffrage" emerged once, i.e., when it was first coined.  "Dubbed as" is idiomatic, though.

Comment: @deadrat - I've not noticed *dubbed as*, but I'm happy to accept your point.

Comment: Check again and give your valuable input @JHCL

Comment: @JHCL Good heavens, don't trust me!  But I did check the google (785K hits) and the Ngram viewer, which has book cites going back to the 1800s, where the term is used to mean "name as a knight" (as by the king's touching the shoulders with a sword).

Comment: Yupp dubbed is indeed conferring knighthood by touching the shoulder with a sword.